# ffmepg get not all jpg files

Tags: shell, ffmpeg

I want to make a timelapse video with somes jpg files in somes directories.
I don't understand why ffmpeg don't catch all the file *.jpg
Thanks for the help

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR_SOURCE="/volume1/homes/krislec/timelapse/test/"

find ${DIR_SOURCE} -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name 'test' ! -name @eaDir | while read -r 
A ; do
ffmpeg -nostdin -framerate 5 -pattern_type glob -i "$("${A}"*.jpg)" 0.mp4
ffmpeg -nostdin -i 0.mp4 -c copy -aspect 16/9 "$A".mp4
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. The images were saved from a cam. I found out that certain images were of zero bytes size, which caused ffmpeg to stop processing in the middle.

My fix was to add this line in my script to remove all empty image files, before starting ffmpeg.

```
find -size 0 -delete
```